# Using endfloat package but keep appendix at the end

Tags: appendices, endfloat

Suppose I have the following article:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nolists, tabhead, fighead]{endfloat}
\begin{document}

\section{Section} This is the start of a section:

\begin{table}[htp]
    \caption{Table}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    Test & Test & Test & Test\\ 
    \hline 
    Test & Test & Test & Test\\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 

\end{table}

This is the start of another section:

\newpage
\section*{Appendix A: Construction of Index}

We construct the index from .........

\end{document}
```

I am using `endfloat` package so tables are pushed towards the end. However, I want the appendix to be at the last page just after tables. Is there a way of doing it and still use `endfloat` package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\processdelayedfloats`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nolists, tabhead, fighead]{endfloat}
\begin{document}

\section{Section} 

This is the start of a section.

\begin{table}[htp]
    \caption{Table}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    Test & Test & Test & Test\\ 
    \hline 
    Test & Test & Test & Test\\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 

\end{table}

This is the end of the section.

\clearpage % ensure all floats are processed
\processdelayedfloats
\clearpage

\section*{Appendix A: Construction of Index}

We construct the index from .........

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have got a table in the appendix, is there any way to keep that table to the endfloat before the appendix?

Comment: @Salhin I don't think there is.